# Android seek bar save progress values with sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, seekbar

I have an issue in save the value of progress of seek bar. I have two seek bar and have an one button and another one `EditText` widget. on click of button `EditText` seek bar value will be save in shared preferences, but on clicking it only save the `EditText`value, not to save the value of seek bar. I try my best but its not working.My code is given below,

Profile2Activity.class

```
public class Profile2Activity extends Activity {
        //TextViews to show details of volume and brightness
        private TextView tVBrightness, tVVolume;
        //SeekBars to set volume and brightness
        private SeekBar sbVolume, sbBrightness;
        //AudioManager object, that will get and set volume
        private AudioManager audioManager;
        //Variable to store brightness value
        private int brightness;
        //Content resolver used as a handle to the system's settings
        private ContentResolver cResolver;
        //Window object, that will store a reference to the current window
        private Window window;
        int maxVolume = 1;

        EditText e2;
        Button b2;
        public static final String MyPREFERENCESS = "MyPrefss";

        public static final String OFFICEWIFI = "officewifi";
        Context context = this;
        private AudioManager myAudioManager;
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

        //Suhas
        String mVolume ;
        String mBrightness;
        public static final String BRIGHTNESS = "brightness";
        public static final String VOLUME = "volume";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile2);
            //Suggests an audio stream whose volume should be changed by the hardware volume controls.
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
           // initializeControls2();
            myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            initializeControls2();

            e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
            b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);

            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCESS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final String officewifi = sharedpreferences.getString(OFFICEWIFI, "");
           // final int brightnesss = Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(BRIGHTNESS, ""));
           // final int volumes = Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(VOLUME, ""));

            e2.setText(officewifi);
            //sbVolume.setProgress(brightnesss);
           // sbBrightness.setProgress(volumes);
        //    String str = sharedpreferences.getString(VOLUME, "");
          //  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)){
            //    int volumes = Integer.parseInt(str);
              //  sbVolume.setProgress(volumes);
           // }
            int volume = sharedpreferences.getInt(VOLUME, 0);
            sbVolume.setProgress(volume);
            int brightness = sharedpreferences.getInt(BRIGHTNESS, 0);
            sbVolume.setProgress(brightness);
         //   String strr = sharedpreferences.getString(BRIGHTNESS, "");
         //   if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(strr)){
          //      int brightnesss = Integer.parseInt(strr);
          //      sbBrightness.setProgress(brightnesss);
          //  }

            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    String officewifi = e2.getText().toString();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                    editor.putString(OFFICEWIFI, officewifi);
    //Suhas
                    editor.putInt(BRIGHTNESS, sbBrightness.getProgress());
                    editor.putInt(VOLUME, sbVolume.getProgress());

                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(Profile2Activity.this, "Thanks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCESS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                }
            });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
    //
                    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo mWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                    if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
                        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        final WifiInfo con = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, con.getSSID()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if (con.getSSID().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\"" + officewifi + "\"")) {

                        } else {
                            myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Now in Ringing Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        } else {
                        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Now in Ringing Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }, 1000);

        }


        private void initializeControls2() {
    //get reference of the UI Controls
            sbVolume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbVolume);
            sbBrightness = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbBrightness);
            tVVolume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVVolume);
            tVBrightness = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVBrightness);

            try {

                audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                //set max progress according to volume
                sbVolume.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
                //get current volume
                sbVolume.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
                //Set the seek bar progress to 1
                sbVolume.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);
                //get max volume
                maxVolume = sbVolume.getMax();
                sbVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                                  boolean fromUser) {
                        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
    //Calculate the brightness percentage
                        float perc = (progress / (float) maxVolume) * 100;

    //Suhas
                        mVolume = ""+perc;

    //Set the brightness percentage
                        tVVolume.setText("Volume: " + (int) perc + " %");
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }


    //Get the content resolver
            cResolver = getContentResolver();

    //Get the current window
            window = getWindow();

    //Set the seekbar range between 0 and 255
            sbBrightness.setMax(255);
    //Set the seek bar progress to 1
            sbBrightness.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

            try {
    //Get the current system brightness
                brightness = System.getInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
            } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    //Throw an error case it couldn't be retrieved
                Log.e("Error", "Cannot access system brightness");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    //Set the progress of the seek bar based on the system's brightness
            sbBrightness.setProgress(brightness);

    //Register OnSeekBarChangeListener, so it can actually change values
            sbBrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    //Set the system brightness using the brightness variable value
                    System.putInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
    //Get the current window attributes
                    LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
    //Set the brightness of this window
                    layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float) 255;
    //Apply attribute changes to this window
                    window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    //Nothing handled here
                }

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    //Set the minimal brightness level
    //if seek bar is 20 or any value below
                    if (progress <= 20) {
    //Set the brightness to 20
                        brightness = 20;
                    } else //brightness is greater than 20
                    {
    //Set brightness variable based on the progress bar
                        brightness = progress;
                    }
    //Calculate the brightness percentage
                    float perc = (brightness / (float) 255) * 100;

    //Suhas
                    mBrightness = ""+perc;
    //Set the brightness percentage
                    tVBrightness.setText("Brightness: " + (int) perc + " %");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please specify clearly your question doesn't understand of this line "but on click it ony save the EditText not save the seek bar."

Comment: is is not saving the seekbar value because you are not saving the seek bar value in shared preferences, if you are then share me the part of code from the above where you are doing it

Comment: sharedprefences does not save the seek bar progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this code:

```
public class Profile2Activity extends Activity {
    //TextViews to show details of volume and brightness
    private TextView tVBrightness, tVVolume;
    //SeekBars to set volume and brightness
    private SeekBar sbVolume, sbBrightness;
    //AudioManager object, that will get and set volume
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    //Variable to store brightness value
    private int brightness;
    //Content resolver used as a handle to the system's settings
    private ContentResolver cResolver;
    //Window object, that will store a reference to the current window
    private Window window;
    int maxVolume = 1;

    EditText e2;
    Button b2;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCESS = "MyPrefss";

    public static final String OFFICEWIFI = "officewifi";
    Context context = this;
    private AudioManager myAudioManager;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    public static final String BRIGHTNESS = "brightness";
    public static final String VOLUME = "volume";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile2);
        //Suggests an audio stream whose volume should be changed by the hardware volume controls.
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        // initializeControls2();
        myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);
        sbVolume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbVolume);
        sbBrightness = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbBrightness);
        tVVolume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVVolume);
        tVBrightness = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVBrightness);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCESS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String officewifi = sharedpreferences.getString(OFFICEWIFI, "");
        e2.setText(officewifi);

        Log.d("VOLUME", "" + sharedpreferences.getInt(VOLUME, 0));
        Log.d("BRIGHTNESS", "" + sharedpreferences.getInt(BRIGHTNESS, 0));

        sbVolume.setProgress(sharedpreferences.getInt(VOLUME, 0));
        sbBrightness.setProgress(sharedpreferences.getInt(BRIGHTNESS, 0));


        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String officewifi = e2.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                editor.putString(OFFICEWIFI, officewifi);
                //Suhas
                editor.putInt(BRIGHTNESS, sbBrightness.getProgress());
                editor.putInt(VOLUME, sbVolume.getProgress());

                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(Profile2Activity.this, "Thanks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
//
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo mWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
                    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    final WifiInfo con = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, con.getSSID()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (con.getSSID().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\"" + officewifi + "\"")) {
                        initializeControls2();
                    } else {
                        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
// Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Now in Ringing Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
// Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Now in Ringing Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);

    }


    private void initializeControls2() {
//get reference of the UI Controls

        try {

            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            //set max progress according to volume
            sbVolume.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            //get current volume
            sbVolume.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            //Set the seek bar progress to 1
            sbVolume.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);
            //get max volume
            maxVolume = sbVolume.getMax();
            sbVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                              boolean fromUser) {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
                    float perc = (progress / (float) maxVolume) * 100;
                    //Set the brightness percentage
                    tVVolume.setText("Volume: " + (int) perc + " %");
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


//Get the content resolver
        cResolver = getContentResolver();

//Get the current window
        window = getWindow();

//Set the seekbar range between 0 and 255
        sbBrightness.setMax(255);
//Set the seek bar progress to 1
        sbBrightness.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

        try {
//Get the current system brightness
            brightness = System.getInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
//Throw an error case it couldn't be retrieved
            Log.e("Error", "Cannot access system brightness");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//Set the progress of the seek bar based on the system's brightness
        sbBrightness.setProgress(brightness);

//Register OnSeekBarChangeListener, so it can actually change values
        sbBrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
//Set the system brightness using the brightness variable value
                System.putInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
//Get the current window attributes
                LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
//Set the brightness of this window
                layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float) 255;
//Apply attribute changes to this window
                window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
//Nothing handled here
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
//Set the minimal brightness level
//if seek bar is 20 or any value below
                if (progress <= 20) {
//Set the brightness to 20
                    brightness = 20;
                } else //brightness is greater than 20
                {
//Set brightness variable based on the progress bar
                    brightness = progress;
                }
//Calculate the brightness percentage
                float perc = (brightness / (float) 255) * 100;
//Set the brightness percentage
                tVBrightness.setText("Brightness: " + (int) perc + " %");
            }
        });
    }

}
```